# Android, how to place two relative layouts, one on the left, and one on the right of the screen?

Tags: android, layout

In my Android App (for landscape screen orientation) I need to place widgets to two relative layouts, one on the left of the screen, and one at the right (to fill the full size).

I prefer working programmatically (I find it more flexible than xml).

Shoud I better use a TableLayout as the parent layout fro my sub-layouts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For just two `RelativeLayouts` next to each other you have plenty of choice to archieve that. A horizontal `LinearLayout` would be the easiest in my opinion.

---

Edit: I never do layouts in code, but since you probably read a lot of docs with XML you should be able to translate this example. Uses a 50/50 space distribution for both layouts.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Edit 2:

Definitely works, just tried this:

```
LinearLayout layoutContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

// Arguments here: width, height, weight
LinearLayout.LayoutParams childLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

RelativeLayout layoutLeft = new RelativeLayout(this);
layoutContainer.addView(layoutLeft, childLp);

RelativeLayout layoutRight = new RelativeLayout(this);
layoutContainer.addView(layoutRight, childLp);
```

Comment: Since you like to work programmatically, take a look at the LinearLayout.LayoutParams: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: The children RelativeLayouts should not use fill_parent for their width, but 0dip.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, bad habit of mine. Fixed it.

Comment: Sorry. it doesn't work. RelativeLayoutes (contrary to LinearLayouts) do not have any weight... Any other idea? :-)

Comment: Just tested it in the emulator with the XML layout. Works for me. There must be something wrong with your translation to the code-based variant. The weight attribute relates to the outer LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But when I replace RelativeLayout with LinearLayout, it does not work. DO you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Method suggested by alextsc didn't work, since RelativeLayouts (contrary to LinearLayouts) do not have any weight.

I did resolve with this (ugly :-() hack:

```
LinearLayout layoutContainer = new LinearLayout(myActivity.this);
layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2;

RelativeLayout layoutLeft = new RelativeLayout(Results.this);
layoutContainer.addView(layoutLeft, width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

RelativeLayout layoutRight = new RelativeLayout(Results.this);
layoutContainer.addView(layoutRight, width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: As stated in my comment above, layout_weight relates to the outer LinearLayout. Check my second edit. This is the same thing that my xml did in code and it does in fact work.

Comment: @alextsc: sorry, it works perfectly, I didn't understand I could use LinearLayout.LayoutParams to add a RelativeLayout... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, thats why i posted it. :)