# How to set android:layout_weight and android:layout_width in code?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone please tell me how to set the android:layout_weight and android:layout_width XML attributes in code for dynamically created views?

Reference: [XML Table layout? Two EQUAL-width rows filled with equally width buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865497/xml-table-layout-two-equal-width-rows-filled-with-equally-width-buttons)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You can also specify fixed pixel sizes in the constructor, instead of the constants. But fixed pixels are a bad idea on android due to the variety of devices.

You can calculate the pixels from a `dp` size though, which is ok:

```
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                                         10, getResources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

*(Here: convert 10dp to a pixel value)*

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make two equal-sized buttons. In XML, you do it like this: <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dip"/>, but I can't figure out how to do that in Java.

Comment: I provided a similiar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056072/android-how-to-place-two-relative-layouts-one-on-the-left-and-one-on-the-right/7056089#7056089). This is with two `RelativeLayout`s, but it works the same way with two `Button`s.

Comment: Yup, that did it! Didn't know you could add LayoutParams to .addView() like that. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that a `LinearLayout` must use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and not the generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` (which compiles but then fails at run-time). This may or may not be true of other layouts but I was scratching my head over this for quite a while

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height))
```

The docs for the constructor says:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int width, int height)
```

Creates a new set of layout parameters with the specified width and height.

Answer (score 3):

Set the layout params of the dynamically created view as below

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            2f
                    );
myView.setLayoutParams(param)
```

Here last argument '2f' specifies the layout weight for the view. We can also use decimal points here.